# How to get the post form parameter values at an Action filter in web api,C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How can I read the post form parameter values using the Request in web api? I have a controller

```
    [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    [AuthenticationAttribute]
    public void PostQuery()
    {
          //some code
    }
```

I have defined AuthenticationAttribute class seperately

```
 public class AuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{


    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
    // I want to read the post paramter values over here
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Run(
            () =>
                {

                });
    }

    public AuthenticationAttribute()
    {

    }
}
```

I want to check the post parameter in the AuthenticateAsync function.

I tried doing

```
context.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

but this string is empty. I am able to read the query parameters using

```
context.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
```

But could not find a way to get the post form parameters. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May I ask why you'd like to access the body of the request from an AuthenticationAttribute? On a side note, I would recommend avoiding that Task.Run()

Answer (score 7):

```
var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

foreach (JToken token in jObj.Children())
{
    if (token is JProperty)
    {
        var prop = token as JProperty;

        if (prop.Name.Equals("skipExternal") && prop.Value.ToString().Equals("True"))
        {
            // Logic...
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I used. I wanted to check weather the parameter `skipExternal` was sent as `True` in post parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with `context.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()`, but from the name, it sounds like it would extract params from the query string. And since you are doing a `POST`, there are no params in the query string (they are in the POST body).

Try this:

```
context.HttpContext.Request.Params["groupId"]
```

Or this:

```
context.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("groupId").AttemptedValue
```

The use of these will depend on how you are implementing your model and providers.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
context.ActionContext.ActionArguments
```

this will get you a `Dictionary<string, object>` where the key is the name of the argument and the value is the argument itself.

This assumes the action method is using model binding to bind the incoming POST values to a model.